# GTK activate_link doesn't work with label uri? gtkmm Gtk::Label and signal_activate_link()?

Tags: gtk, gtkmm, libsigc++

I have a handler function:

```
bool test( const Glib::ustring& uri )
{
    MessageBoxA( NULL, "hello", NULL, 0 );
    return true;
}
```

and I connect

```
label2.set_markup( "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>" );
sigc::connection conn = label2.signal_activate_link().connect( sigc::ptr_fun( test ) );
```

I don't understand why that doesn't work. When I click on Google I can see it's using the default URI handler not mine.

Comment: anyone have any idea about this? it's driving me a little nuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make sure my function was called before the default. I'm guessing what happens is the default signal handler returns true and therefore the signal is not propagated?

```
  /** Connects a signal to a signal handler.
   * For instance, connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this, &TheClass::on_something) );
   *
   * @param slot The signal handler, usually created with sigc::mem_fun(), or sigc::ptr_fun().
   * @param after Whether this signal handler should be called before or after the default signal handler.
   */
  sigc::connection connect(const SlotType& slot, bool after = true)
    { return sigc::connection(connect_(slot, after)); }
```

Here is the correct code:

```
label2.signal_activate_link().connect( sigc::ptr_fun( test ), false );
```